# In an integral domain, show that $a$ and $b$ are associates if and only if $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

This question if from "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" -Galian (9th ed.) Chapter 18 #2.  It is an assigned homework problem.  I'm hitting a wall trying to crack this problem.  I'm sure it is relatively simple but I'm missing some key component.  This is where my thinking and research has taken me.  Please help get me over the hurdle.

Let $D$ be an integral domain and $a$ and $b$ be non-zero elements of $D$ such that $a$ and $b$ are associates.  Then $a=ub$ and $b=va$ for some units $u,v\in D$.  Clearly, $u$ and $v$ are inverses, but I can't make the mental connection that $ub\in \langle b\rangle$ or $va\in \langle a\rangle$.

Associates defined as: Elements $a$ and $b$ of integral domain $D$ are associates if $a=ub$ where $u$ is a unit of $D$.

Train of thought:

$a=vua \implies a\sim ua$.  (this seems trivial since $a=ua$ given $u$ must have an inverse.)

There is no indication that $D$ must be finite, so we're not guaranteed that any elements in $\langle a \rangle$ contain any units or that the subgroup of $D$ generated by $a$ (or $b$) is itself an integral domain.  If $\langle a\rangle$ is an integral domain then it becomes simple to show that $b=ua\in \langle a\rangle$.

Please help me along.

Comment: To show $\langle a\rangle =\langle b\rangle$ you need to show that $a\in\langle b\rangle$ and $b\in\langle a\rangle$. This means you need to show $a$ is a multiple of $b$ and that $b$ is a multiple of $a$. For the other direction, you may assume that $a$ is a multiple of $b$ and that $b$ is a multiple of $a$, then you need to show that in fact, $a$ is a *unit* multiple of $b$ and that $b$ is a *unit* multiple of $a$.

Comment: To take this further, if $a=pb$ and $b=qa$ for some $p,q\in D$ then $a=pqa$. Since $D$ is an *integral domain* we can cancel, so $1=pq$. Then what?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I think that may be part of my hang-up.  I'm having trouble processing the notation in my mind.  $\langle a\rangle$ is $\{a,a+a,a+a+a,...\}$ and $ua$ obviously an element of $\langle a\rangle$ (i.e. $a+a+a+...$ $u$ times?)  I may be mixing up the addition and multiplication in thinking about the rings.

Comment: Typically $\langle a\rangle$ is defined to be the *ideal generated by $a$*, in other words all multiples of $a$ by elements of $D$. How exactly does that book define $\langle a\rangle$?

Comment: But if $\langle a\rangle = \{a,a^2,a^3,...\}$ I'm back to square one and not seeing connection.

Comment: We should have $\langle a\rangle=\{fa:f\in D\}$. What does the book define it as?

Comment: The book defines $\langle a\rangle$ in the section on groups (rather than rings) and the operations defined in the groups varied.  Since rings have both "addition" and "multiplication", I'm getting confused.

Comment: Ah okay. So $\langle a\rangle$ in the context of *groups* would be $a,a^2,a^3$ etc. but since this is a ring theoretic question, I'm willing to bet $\langle a\rangle$ is the *ideal generated by $a$* rather than the cyclic group generated by $a$. Has the book introduced ideals yet?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Yes, but the notation for "Ideal generated by" isn't clearly defined that I can tell.  I know that an if $A$ is an ideal and $a\in A$ then for any $r\in $ ring $R$ then $ar,ra\in A$.  That would simplify my problem considerably if $\langle a\rangle$ is an ideal.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I found the definition in the book.  It is buried in an example.  For anyone that may follow the book in the future the definition is on page 250 buried inside Example 3.  Very easy to miss.  Thank you.

Comment: Got first half of proof now:  $a=ub\implies a\in\langle b\rangle$ and $\langle a\rangle \subseteq \langle b\rangle$...........  $b=va\implies b\in\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle \subseteq \langle a\rangle$ ....  Together, we have $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: Yes. Looking good. For the other direction, see my second comment if you get stuck.

Comment: Please state in the question which definition of "associate" you are using (several are in use).

Answer (score 2):

**If $a$ and $b$ are associates:**

Let $D$ be an integral domain with non-zero elements $a,b\in D$ such that $a$ and $b$ are associates.

For some units $u,v\in D$, $a=ub$ and $b=va$ (by definition of associates).

$a=ub\implies a\in\langle b\rangle$ and $\langle a\rangle\subseteq\langle b\rangle$.

$b=va\implies b\in\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle\subseteq\langle a\rangle$.

Taken together: $\langle b\rangle\subseteq\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle a\rangle\subseteq\langle b\rangle\implies \langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$

**If $a=pb$ and $b=qa$ for some $a,b,p,q\in D$ (where $D$ is an integral domain):**

$a=pb\implies a=pqa\implies pq=1$ which implies that $p$ and $q$ are inverses and by definition are units in $D$.  Thus $a\sim b$ and as shown above $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: I like it. Very good!